# Should I re-fork for a second pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

1. Someone has a cool project on GitHub.
2. I fork it to make some changes.
3. I submit a pull request.
4. I notice something else I think could be improved.

Do I fork the original project again to change the new fork and submit a pull request from there or do I change my original fork and submit another pull request with that fork as head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to fork twice. The best way is to create a branch in your fork for each subject / pull request. It's branches that push/pull operates on in Git and therefore in Github pull requests, not whole repositories.

It's best for each of your branches to start with a commit that is in the original project, so that the maintainer can consider both pull requests independently of each other.

Comment: Of course! I'm quite new to git, so I hadn't thought of branches.